# A working stored procedure returns null value only when called from asp.net

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, vb.net, stored-procedures

I created the following stored procedure to insert data into table.

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[Sp_AddAircraft] 
-- Add the parameters for the stored procedure here
    @ACFT_Reg varchar(50), 
    @ACFT_MSN int,
    @ACFT_Manufacturer varchar(50),
    @ACFT_Type_P1 varchar(50),
    @ACFT_Type_P2 int,
    @ACFT_DOM date,
    @ACFT_ETOPS bit,
    @ACFT_TOT float,
    @ACFT_TOC int

AS
BEGIN
-- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from
-- interfering with SELECT statements.
SET NOCOUNT ON;

-- Insert statements for procedure here
IF EXISTS(SELECT * FROM Aircraft
          WHERE ACFT_MSN = @ACFT_MSN 
            And ACFT_Manufacturer = @ACFT_Manufacturer)
    Return (5)
ELSE
    INSERT INTO [Aircraft] 
        ([ACFT_Reg], [ACFT_MSN], [ACFT_Manufacturer], [ACFT_Type_P1],
         [ACFT_Type_P2], [ACFT_DOM], [ACFT_ETOPS], [ACFT_TOT], [ACFT_TOC])
    VALUES (@ACFT_Reg, @ACFT_MSN, @ACFT_Manufacturer, @ACFT_Type_P1,
            @ACFT_Type_P2, @ACFT_DOM, @ACFT_ETOPS, @ACFT_TOT, @ACFT_TOC)
    Return (1)
END
```

I check unique constraint (a combination of `ACFT_MSN` and `ACFT_Manufacturer`) if it exists the stored procedure returns a value 5, if not it returns a value 1 and inserts a new record.

The procedure is working fine in SQL Server 2008 Management studio.

When I call it from asp.net the browser throw this error

"Conversion from type 'DBNull' to type 'Short' is not valid."

The Return parameter is defined in DataSource as follow:

```
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:NileAirConnectionString1 %>" 
         InsertCommand="Sp_AddAircraft" InsertCommandType="StoredProcedure" OnInserted="SqlDataSource1_Inserted" 
         ProviderName="<%$ ConnectionStrings:NileAirConnectionString1.ProviderName %>">
            <InsertParameters>
                <asp:Parameter Name="ACFT_Reg" Type="String" />
                <asp:Parameter Name="ACFT_MSN" Type="Int32" />
                <asp:Parameter Name="ACFT_Manufacturer" Type="String" />
                <asp:Parameter Name="ACFT_Type_P1" Type="String" />
                <asp:Parameter Name="ACFT_Type_P2" Type="Int32" />
                <asp:Parameter DbType="Date" Name="ACFT_DOM" />
                <asp:Parameter Name="ACFT_ETOPS" Type="Boolean" />
                <asp:Parameter Name="ACFT_TOT" Type="Double" />
                <asp:Parameter Name="ACFT_TOC" Type="Int32" />
                <asp:Parameter Name="R" Type="Int16" Direction="ReturnValue" />
            </InsertParameters>
        </asp:SqlDataSource>
```

I read the parameter in SqlDataSource1_Inserted event as follow:

```
Protected Sub SqlDataSource1_Inserted(sender As Object, e As SqlDataSourceStatusEventArgs)
    Dim G As Int16
    G = e.Command.Parameters("@R").Value
    If G = 5 Then
        Lbl_ACFT_Doublication.CssClass = "WarningMessages"
        Lbl_ACFT_Doublication.Text = "Aircraft already exists"
    ElseIf G = 1 Then
        Lbl_ACFT_Doublication.CssClass = "AckMessages"
        Lbl_ACFT_Doublication.Text = "Aircraft was added succesfully"
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: The ReturnValue from a stored procedure is an int. You shouldn't be using Return in your procedure code. I would just remove the return in your procedure and drop the "R" parameter and it will probably work fine.

Comment: If you want to get that return value in case you have already the record  then you should RETURN 5 not SELECT 5. The second one is not passed inside the ReturnValue parameter.

Comment: The line where your have SELECT (5), change it to SELECT 5 AS R and the line where you have RETURN (1), change it to SELECT 1 AS R, as in your current Stored procedure there is nothing named R, so VB code gets NULL in it and converting it to Int16 throws exeception. And also in the else part use BEGIN and END, as it will have 2 commands (INSERT AND SELECT)

Comment: Sean Lange, Thank you for your help but If I remove the Return from the stored procedure it will work fine and returns 0 when success. The problem is that I need to have a return value from the stored procedure to use it to display an error message to the user to inform about either the insertion done successfully or data already exists in table.

Comment: Steve, Thanks a lot. I changed SELECT to RETURN and still receive the same error.

Comment: Imran Balouch, Thanks for help. tried your recommendations but unfortunately still receiving the same error.

Answer (score 0):

Check the input variables for the insert. One of them is not set to something that can be implicitly converted to the needed type.  Make sure none of the source controls for the insert parameters is null/Nothing

Comment: I checked everything but I found nothing. So far still have the problem. Could not figure out the cause. I tried another new website with the same code and procedure and it gives me another error "An SqlParameter with ParameterName '@R' is not contained by this SqlParameterCollection."

Comment: give the return value parameter a `DefaultValue` of zero

Comment: In your code `G = e.Command.Parameters("@R").Value` verify that Value is not null.  Not all return paths in your sp (as posted) have a return value

Comment: I am testing by data concerning two paths, either duplicated data or not. So SP should return either 5 or 1 but it returns null.

Comment: `Select 5` is not the same as `Return 5`. `Select` returns a dataset, `Return` is the return value from and executed stored procedure.  Return uses your R parameter - Select does not

Comment: Ok well, I changed the Select and make both Return. I still have the same problem.

Comment: if you place a breakpoint where you assign `G` the return value, can you see the contents of the return parameter `ListItem` in the `Command.Parameters` collection?

Answer (score 0):

An old question, but it just bit me; this was probably the problem:

`<asp:Parameter Name="ACFT_Type_P1" Type="String" />` is missing `Size="50"`.

I just had the same problem; my `inserted` was firing, but the stored procedure wasn't executing and my returnvalue was always NULL.  Because I was crashing at the point of checking the returnvalue, I wasn't getting to see the error message complaining about the missing string size.